# How to make Edges on a vis.js network non-selectable?

Tags: javascript, graph, vis.js

Is is possible to configure the options of a network in order to make edges not to respond on the click event?

If not how could I catch this particular event and do something like a `preventDefault()`?

So far, I have tried this in the network options but it doesn't seem to work.

```
onEditEdge: function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a little too late but I had the same problem.  My solution was to create a click event that clears the selection if an edge is clicked.

```
  // Disable selecting edges
  network.on('click', ({ nodes, edges }) => {
    if (nodes.length == 0 && edges.length > 0) {
      network.setSelection({
        nodes: [],
        edges: []
      })
    }
  })
```